# Duplicated windows 8 recovery partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

Let's me describe what am I trying to do first. I bought a laptop from HP(HP ENVY TouchSmart 15-j137tx) with windows 8.1 in it and plan to dual boot it into windows 7 and windows 8.1(for debugging purposes). The windows 8.1 just come with a recovery partition.

I made a clean installation of windows 7 first(I didn't format the windows 8.1 recovery partition) and trying to install a windows 8.1 now. I can see and explore the recovery partition in windows explorer but it show "File Not Found" when I try to access through command prompt. When look into disk management, there are two partitions(duplicated) with drive letter D and it just showing "Help" when I right click and try to change the letter of the drive. (tried to post a screen shot here but get this error"You need to have 10 reputations to post an image")

I believe this caused the hp recovery manager cannot detect my windows 8.1. How can I fix this without format the drive? I need the data inside to install my windows 8.1

Comment: Your trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 and Windows 8.0?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows 8.1(The laptop come with Windows 8.1)